# How to send IEnumerable list from Ajax to Controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a web application  in MVC3 and i'm using Telerik Grid Batch Editing.

Batch Editing have save changes button which returns UPDATED COLUMNS to controller IEnumerable list like

```
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult Update(IEnumerable<Customers> updated)
    {
        ///user codes
    }
```

but how to collect updated rows and make array send like IEnumerable list from Javascript with ajax to Controller ?

**EDIT**
I'm putting my view png

[image]

I just want to send updated rows data to Controller and Save Changes button can do this but before thje send values i just want to ask to user "Are you sure to Load?" and after the send data I want to refresh all the page

So i thinked to do this with ajax request because i'm also using batch editing with ajax requests

Do you have any exprience for this situation?

Comment: Why do you send it with JavaScript? You shouldn't try to manually parse it. Please post your View so that we can see the code in question.

Comment: Hi! @AndreiV I pasted my view.jpg and i explaned what i want.

Comment: You should just add an event listener on your submit button using JavaScript (or jQuery). On click, you just show a `confirm`.

Comment: @AndreiV i tried to put event but after i click i have to send IEnumeratable list to my Update function in Controller

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the AJAX POST as I have used in my Tested Javascript function as::

```
function TestAjax() {
    var Test = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Test.push({ ID: i, Name: "RJ" });
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: rootUrl('Home/TestPost'),
        contentType: "application/json",
        //data: { Test: JSON.stringify( data) },
        data:JSON.stringify( {Test: Test}),
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Succeded");
        }
    });
}
```

And on Server Side(i.e. In Controller)  use something Like::

```
public ActionResult TestPost(IEnumerable<TestViewModel> Test)
    {
        return Json(3);
    }
```

The ViewModel Contains different propeties which are of different datatypes as::

```
public class TestViewModel
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

This is working fine. May be this will help you.

Comment: Thnx @Rahul I understand what you do but i want to send all updated row data and some data are decimal some data is string also how can i catch the updated rows in the grid??

Comment: @saul There isn't anything with dataType.
As you had seen in my given Example, I am Passing ID(long) and Name(string).

Ok let me edit my answer with viewmodel also.