# Multiple Bind(Prefix = "...") in ASP.Net Core 3 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've an ASP.Net MVC 4 application that I'm porting to ASP.Net Core 3.0 MVC.

I'm trying to port this method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSave(
  [Bind(Prefix = "new")]IEnumerable<C_Data> newItems,
  [Bind(Prefix = "updated")]IEnumerable<C_Data> updatedItems,
  [Bind(Prefix = "deleted")]IEnumerable<C_Data> deletedItems))
{
}
```

In the post AJAX (in JavaScript from the web browser) I'm sending the values as *JSON* like this

```
{
  "new[0].Id":3,
  "new[0].SID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "new[0].Name":"asd"
}
```

Here's the C_Data class

```
public class C_Data
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Guid SID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(40)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But the three parameters are empty when this action is executed.

Here's the error I get in the *ModelState*

"The JSON value could not be converted to C_Data"

Anyone please can tell me how to port this method?

Thank you.

PD: This action is in an MVC controller not an API controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Bind Prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1317523/11683)

Comment: you know that `BindAttribute` is for forms not json? you json should be `{"newItems":[{"Id" : 3,"SID":...}], "updatedItems":[...]}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345335/how-to-send-ienumerable-list-from-ajax-to-controller) that should help.

It looks like you should be able to use C_Data object, put it in an array, and stringify it in the AJAX call, receive an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

For Asp.Net Core, there are two ways to bind the model, `ModelBinding` and `JsonInputFormatter`. For sending request with json, it will use `JsonInputFormatter` and `Bind` will not work.

In general, I would suggest you try option below:

1. Controller Action

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult DoSave([FromBody]ItemModel itemModel)
   {
       return Ok("Worked");     
   }
   ```
2. Model

   ```
   public class ItemModel
   {
       public IEnumerable<C_Data> NewItems { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<C_Data> UpdatedItems { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<C_Data> DeletedItems { get; set; }

   }
   ```
3. Request Json

   ```
   {
       "newItems":[{
           "Id":3,
           "SID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
           "Name":"asd"
       }]
   }
   ```